Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-***:Unable to execute SonarScanner analysis: Fail to get bootstrap index from server:
I am newly run this project anyone guide me to run this project. I am mention the details for ur reference
machine:1 ( i installed the following packages in this machine) java 17 , git, apache-maven-3.8.8 , Jenkins ,docker
machine:2 ( i installed the following packages in this machine) sonarqube-6.7.6 ,java-1.8.0
Here i enclosed POM>XML file  for ur reference
<build>
    <plugins>    
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
</plugin> 
    </plugins>
</build>    
</project>

when i run the** jenkins i got this below error**,

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.11.0.3922:sonar (default-cli) on project myweb: Unable to execute SonarScanner analysis: Fail to get bootstrap index from server: Connect timed out -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[Pipeline] }
WARN: Unable to locate 'report-task.txt' in the workspace. Did the SonarScanner succeed?
[Pipeline] // withSonarQubeEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
anyone kindly giveme the solution.
I try to run Jenkins pipeline(sample project), but am getting lot of errors, still now i done some but in sonarqube I getting that error


Does this answer your question? SonarQube: Fail to get bootstrap index from server: Status returned by url [http://hostname:9095/sonar/batch/index] is not valid: [403]
